# What affects the speed of an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I am aware that the **amount of data being sent to the server, as well as how much of information is returned** in the call have impact on how fast the call would be.

But, what I am eager to know is, whether any of these measures below would have an impact on sending the information to the server, processing the call on the server and finally what is returned:

- User's network connection speed
- Server configs and speed
- DataType
  (HTML,jsonp and etc)

If I have missed out any other factor that matters, please do mention it as well.

Comment: yes, yes, no - users network speed is only a part of the network side of the equation ... congestion, speed issues, latency etc **anywhere on the route between users workstation and server** will effect the overall "speed" of an Ajax call

Comment: You missed server connection speed. This caught me and my team by surprise once. We launched a Facebook app to accompany our webapp and the server slowed to a crawl. When we SSH into the server we found that the server load was not too high. In fact it was more than acceptable - the server itself wasn't busy. It took us a while to realize that our 1Mbps connection was the choking point. We upgraded our hosting plan and moved all our static files to a CDN the same day.

Comment: @slebetman, thanks for pointing that out. Quite something that you might not care about, but it will get you in trouble. Perfect :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events in an Ajax call:

1. Create Ajax request in client Javascript
2. Initiate Ajax call
3. Browser looks up DNS entry to get IP address for target server
4. Browser makes TCP connection to server
5. Server accepts incoming connection
6. Browser initiates sending of request to server
7. Network delivers request to server
8. Server receives incoming request and routes it to appropriate request handler
9. Server request handler process the request and creates a response
10. Server sends back response
11. Network delivers response back to client
12. Client receives response and parses it for consumption by the code
13. Client code receives Ajax response
14. TCP connection is closed.

Lots of these steps are connection mechanics.  For quick performance, all those connection steps must be quick.

The steps that you control directly from the client Javascript are really only 6 (size of data you are sending) and 10-11 (size of server response that you asked for).

Many of these steps are influenced by either the throughput of the network connection or the latency of the network connection or both.  Mobile connections (3g/4g/5g) often have slower latency than other types of connections.

As you can see that lots of the steps involve the responsiveness of the server.

If SSL is involved in the connection, then there are quite a few more steps in the connection mechanics.

HTTP2 connections (if supported at both ends) can speed up some of the connection mechanics by essentially keeping a connection alive to be used for multiple requests so a new socket doesn't have to be created from scratch each time.

---

The main things that a client can do are:

1. Reduce the number of Ajax requests.  Try to structure code on both client and server so that a client can request all the data it needs in one request rather than needing make several different requests as part of one operation.
2. If the client is making multiple requests, then try to parallelize them (launch multiple requests in flight at the same time) rather than make request, wait for response, make next request.  Serializing requests substantially increases the end-to-end time.
3. Connect via a fast network.
4. Send the smallest amount of data required.
5. Request the smallest amount of data required.

Comment: Quite detailed and nicely explained. Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can change the network protocol from HTTP to HTTP2 ([SPDY](https://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper)).

**Goals for SPDY**

The SPDY project defines and implements an application-layer protocol for the web which greatly reduces latency. The high-level goals for SPDY are:

- To target a 50% reduction in page load time. Our preliminary results have come close to this target.
- To minimize deployment complexity. SPDY uses TCP as the underlying transport layer, so  requires no changes to existing networking infrastructure.
- To avoid  the need for any changes to content by website authors. The only   changes required to support SPDY are in the client user agent and web server applications.
- To bring together like-minded parties interested in exploring protocols as a way of solving the latency problem. We hope to develop this new protocol in partnership with the open-source community and industry specialists.

Comment: This is a very good option and it's well explained. Thanks loads mate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reduce the Number of Ajax Requests
2. Use GET Requests When Appropriate
3. Reduce the Amount of Data Transmitted
4. Optimize the Server
5. Improve the Performance of the JavaScript Code
6. Lastly , each request depends on your network bandwidth